# Display all the JAC security providers and their service type with Algorithm

Tags: java, security, provider

i want to create a simple java code that display  all the security Providers with :

- Name
- info
- service Type
- Algorithm

## Main Activity.java

```
import java.io.ObjectInputStream.GetField;
import java.security.Provider;
import java.security.Provider.Service;
import java.security.Security;

public class MainActivity {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Availble Providers are:");
        Provider[] providerList = Security.getProviders();
        for (int i = 0; i < providerList.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("[" + (i + 1) + "] - Name: "
                    + providerList[i].getName());

            System.out.println("Information:\n" + providerList[i].getInfo());

            System.out
                    .print("Here are all providers with types of service and algorithm provided:\n");

        }
        
        for (int i = 0; i < serviceList.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("- Name: " + providerList[i].getName() + "\n");
            System.out.print("Service Type: " + serviceList[i].getType()
                    + "Algorithm: " + serviceList[i].getAlgorithm());

        }
    }
}
```

before the second for loop i need to initialize the services to be able to call the service type and Algorithm.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need your second loop to be inside the first loop as you need the current provider so you can call its `getServices` method. Something like:

```
import java.security.Provider;
import java.security.Provider.Service;
import java.security.Security;
import java.util.Set;

public class MainActivity
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    Provider [] providerList = Security.getProviders();
    for (Provider provider : providerList)
     {
       System.out.println("Name: "  + provider.getName());
       System.out.println("Information:\n" + provider.getInfo());

       Set<Service> serviceList = provider.getServices();
       for (Service service : serviceList)
        {
          System.out.println("Service Type: " + service.getType() + " Algorithm " + service.getAlgorithm());
        }
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: @ grep-449  i tried your answer but it give me an error that say :  provider cannot be resolved  how to fix this error ??

Comment: I only gave the core code. I have edited the answer to include the whole program.

Comment: it work very well it was my mistake in writing thank you